# How to skip values in Random.Range? In Unity/C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random, unicode, range

facing issue with randomising the randomLetter for non latin script. in my script, in the unicode characters table, 4 unicode values are non existent. need to skip those characters while Random.Range() is running. what is the workaround? declare an array? or declare a list? or something else? please help.
Working code for Latin script:

```
{
private void OnEnable()
    {
        var i = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 26);
_randomLetter = (char) ('a' + i);

        GetComponent<TMP_Text>().text = _randomLetter.ToString();
    }
```

Bengali script code:

```
private void OnEnable()
    {
        var i = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 16);  //12 vowels in bengali but here 16 as range including non-existent values

        _randomLetter = (char) ('অ' + i);

        GetComponent<TMP_Text>().text = _randomLetter.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: (1) Create a static array with the legal values in. (2) Create a random number in the range 0 .. array size -1. (3) Use that random number to index the array to return the required value.

Answer (score 1):

easiest way is to build a list of all the allowed characters, and generate a random index into this list. Note that a string can be used like a list of characters.

```
const string allowedCharacters = "abe";
var randomIndex = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,allowedCharacters.Length);
var randomCharacter = allowedCharacters[randomIndex];
```

Another easy way is to use [rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling)

Comment: I recommend creating a static field with for `allowedCharacters` so a new array isn't created every time.